# Difference between function expression in global scope and function declaration

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I'm puzzled by something in my js. Normally I define functions like this:

```
function f(){
    // do stuff
}
```

but I can also define functions like this:

```
f = function(){
    // do stuff
}
```

I always thought there is no difference between them, but I now found that this is working:

```
f = function(){
    alert('IT WORKS!!');
}

function createCallback(request){
    request.done(function(data){
        var html = '';
        data['result'].forEach(function(bill){
            html += "<tr onclick=\"f();\"><td>" + bill.title + "</td></tr>";
        });
        $("#someId").html(html);
    });
}
```

but when I define `f` as follows:

```
function f(){
    alert('IT WORKS!!');
}
```

and I click on the row, it gives a `ReferenceError: f is not defined`.

So I wonder: what is actually the difference between `function f(){}` and `f = function(){}`?

Comment: I suggest to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*When you define a function without using `var` statement, by default the function will be defined as a property in the global scope.*

Quoting [MDN documentation on `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description),

> **Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed**. The differences between declared and undeclared variables are:
>
> 1. Declared variables are constrained in the execution context in which they are declared. Undeclared variables are always global.
> 2. Declared variables are created before any code is executed. Undeclared variables do not exist until the code assigning to them is executed.
> 3. Declared variables are a non-configurable property of their execution context (function or global). Undeclared variables are configurable (e.g. can be deleted).
>
> Because of these three differences, failure to declare variables will very likely lead to unexpected results. **Thus it is recommended to always declare variables, regardless of whether they are in a function or global scope**. And in [ECMAScript 5 strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), assigning to an undeclared variable throws an error.

So, when you define with `function function_name(...){...}` syntax, it will be in the current scope.

Since the second function definition is in the global scope `tr`'s onclick can find `f`. Try using `var` statement like this

```
var f = function(){
    alert('IT WORKS!!');
}
```

you will get the same `ReferenceError: f is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `var` statement. The function is defined globally when using `f = function(){ }`. This is why it’s accessible from the `onclick` handler and the other is not.

Please also read [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) as suggested by @Nehal.

Comment: I don't see how "forgot" is a valid way to describe "chose not to use".